# python3.5: with aiohttp is it possible to serve several responses concurently?

Tags: asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using the latest version (`1.0.2`) of aiohttp with python3.5 I have the following server code

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp.web import Application, Response, StreamResponse, run_app


async def long(request):
    resp = StreamResponse()
    name = request.match_info.get('name', 'Anonymous')
    resp.content_type = 'text/plain'
    for _ in range(1000000):
        answer = ('Hello world\n').encode('utf8')

        await resp.prepare(request)
        resp.write(answer)
    await resp.write_eof()
    return resp


async def init(loop):

    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_get('/long', long)
    return app

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
run_app(app)
```

If I then run two curl requests `curl http://localhost:8080/long` in different terminals, only the first one will receive data

My thought was that using `asyncio` you could, in a monothreaded code,  start serving other response, while an other is waiting for I/O

Most of the code I found online about concurent+asyncio only talks about the client side, but not server side

Am I missing something or is my comprehension of how asyncio works is flawed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push `await resp.drain()` after `resp.write()` for giving `aiohttp` a chance to switch between tasks:

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp.web import Application, Response, StreamResponse, run_app


async def long(request):
    resp = StreamResponse()
    name = request.match_info.get('name', 'Anonymous')
    resp.content_type = 'text/plain'
    await resp.prepare(request)  # prepare should be called once
    for _ in range(1000000):
        answer = ('Hello world\n').encode('utf8')

        resp.write(answer)
        await resp.drain()  # switch point
    await resp.write_eof()
    return resp


async def init(loop):

    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_get('/long', long)
    return app

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
run_app(app)
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason, my brain started to think `await resp.prepare(request)` was the thing doing the switch point. However, with your code, out of my two curls, I still only got one receiving data

Comment: Maybe the reason is: `'Hello world\n'` is too short for output buffer overwhelming. Adding `await asyncio.sleep(0)` will explicitly switch the task.

Comment: indeed, now that I've added `asyncio.sleep(0)` my 2 curls are receiving bytes (works also if I remove the call to `drain`), should I prefer this solution in case of workload where small packet of bytes are send once at a time ?

Comment: `sleep(0)` switches the task immediately. `drain()` switches only if the output buffer is overloaded. Thus `sleep()` helps for small data packets but `drain` is recommended for real use cases like uploading 10M long files.

Comment: I see, would it mean, in my case drain() will finally switch after the Nth iteration of the loop with N big enough ?

Comment: yes, the switch will happen after output buffer overloading (reaching high watermark).